# seamless integration of webpack in symfony-(dev)-docker environment

Tags: symfony, docker, webpack

i'm currenty working on the migration from symfony assetic bundle to webpack. "It's easy" they said. "You can switch in no time" they said. And now im hanging the second day on it with nothing.

Let me describe the environment:

We have some docker container handled with docker-compose:

- nginx
- php-fpm
- node (node:latest with addionally yarn)
- ... some others (which are irrelevant here)

It's a standard symfony 3.3 Application with the following structure:

```
app
  Resources
    assets
      scss
        some-common.scss
      common.js
src
  ABundle
    Resources
      assets
        js
          some.js
          another.js
        common.js
        bundle.js
  BBundle
    Resources
      assets
        js
          some-other.js
        scss
          custom-font.scss
          jet-another.scss
        font
          custom.ttf
          custom...
        img
          some.jpg
        bundle.js
vendor
   user/bundle
     src
        UserBundle
          Resources
            assets
              js
                other.js
              scss
                another.scss
              img
                some-other.jpg
              common.js
              bundle.js
web
   static <= the output 
     manifest.json <= is required for get the the filenames for symfony

     abundle.somecrpytichash.js
     bbundle.somecrpytichash.css
     bbundle.somecrpytichash.js
     userbundle.somecrpytichash.js
     userbundle.somecrpytichash.css
     common.somecrpytichash.js
     common.somecrpytichash.css

     custom.ttf
     custom....
     some.jpg (or another autogenerated name, eg. also with hash)
     some-other.jpg
```

And now a more detailed description what i hardly try to get:

In develop case the docker container "node" should be in a watch mode watching changes on changes in the assets.
In addition if possible HMR is working (its CAN, not a MUST) - the "node" container is available for the other containers and any port can be mappped.
(Is webpack-hot-middleware here the correct thing?)

The naming follow simple roules: all code which is required over the global application will be found in the common.js entry points. It can be external dependencies like jquery or foundation-sites or comming from the bundle itself.
The bundle.js instead contains all the code that is only reqired in this bundle.

In the end there should be only (max) 2 js on each site the common.js and the bundle specific.js file as well as the css files (of common und bundle).

The names of the files (and folder structue) in the web/static folder has an exemplary nature. The only required thing is, that the output get hashes since it's better for deployment.

Seems to be easy in description, but not in build it :-/

Comment: I am not sure if you really require a "node" docker container to run webpack, as you would be doing that locally & not on the server.

From what I understand HMR uses a socket to update chunks of code in a standard node app. Unfortunately, at the moment I don't know enough to get HMR working (if it is even possible), though I would image you need to pass the socket through from webpack -> nginx -> php to get it to inject into your template.